# Morra - Odds and Even

Tags: c

Im writing a code that evolves the computer and I entering numbers and added them together to see who wins.
There are three problems:

- Problem 1:  When I try to recall the 'main()' function the 'game()' wont appear.
- Problem 2: I can't seem to run the code forever until user decides to stop.
- Problem 3: The point system isn't accurate enough.

Any help would be grateful.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

    int human_fingers;
    int comp_fingers;
    int menu_choice;
    int answer;
    int count = 1;
    int point1 = 0, point2 = 0;
    int total;

   
void intro() {
    printf("Welcome to Morra - Odds and Even!\n\n");
    printf("The rules of the game are pretty simple\n");
    printf("You and the computer will pick a side each round\n");
    printf("You must enter a number and the total sum will determine the winner!\n\n");
}

void example() {
    printf("You picked even, by default the computer will be odd this round\n");
    printf("You entered 3 and the computer entered 5\n");
    printf("3 + 5 = 8, so you win because you choose even!\n");
}

void game() {
    while(count < 7)
   
    {
        count = count + 1;
       
    printf("Enter a number to choose a side:\n");
    printf("Even [1] / Odd [2]\n");
   
    scanf("%d", &menu_choice);
   
    while((menu_choice<1) || (menu_choice>2)){
    printf("Invalid entry, please Enter 1-2: ");
    scanf("%d",&menu_choice);}
   
   
    if(menu_choice == 1)
    {
        printf("The computer will be odd this turn\n");
        printf("\nPlease enter an number (1-10)\n");
        scanf("%d", &human_fingers);
       
        while((human_fingers<1) || (human_fingers>10)){
        printf("Invalid entry, please enter 1-10:");
        scanf("%d",&human_fingers);}

       
        printf("Computer is choosing a number....\n");
       
        srand(time(NULL));
        comp_fingers = rand() % 10 + 1;
       
       
        printf("You: %d\n", human_fingers);
        printf("Computer: %d\n", comp_fingers);
       
        int result;
       
        result = human_fingers + comp_fingers;
        printf("Total is %d\n", result);
       
        total = result % 2;
       
        if(total == 0)
        {
        printf("This turn goes to You!\n\n");
        printf("You: %d\n", point1 + 1);
        printf("Computer: %d\n\n", point2 + 0 );
        point1++;
        }
        else
        {
        printf("This turn goes to Computer!\n\n");
        printf("You: %d\n", point1 + 0 );
        printf("Computer: %d\n\n", point2 + 1);
        point2++;
        }
        
        

       
    }
   
    if(menu_choice == 2)
    {
        printf("The computer will be even this turn\n");
        printf("\nPlease enter an number (1-10)\n");
        scanf("%d", &human_fingers);
     
        while((human_fingers<1) || (human_fingers>10)){
        printf("Invalid entry, please enter 1-10:");
        scanf("%d",&human_fingers);}
       
        printf("Computer is choosing a number...\n");
       
        srand(time(NULL));
        comp_fingers = rand() % 10 + 1;
       
       
        printf("You: %d\n", human_fingers);
        printf("Computer: %d\n", comp_fingers);
       
        int result;
       
        result = human_fingers + comp_fingers;
        printf("Total is %d\n", result);
       
        total = result % 1;
       
        if(total == 0)
        {
        printf("This turn goes to Computer!\n\n");
        printf("You: %d\n", point1 + 0);
        printf("Computer: %d\n\n", point2 + 1);
        point1++;
        }
        else
        {
        printf("This turn goes to You!\n\n");
        printf("You: %d\n", point1 + 1);
        printf("Computer: %d\n\n", point2 + 0 );
        point2++;
        }
        
        
    }

    

    }
      if(point1 > point2)
    printf("You won, you beat the computer!\n");
    else
    printf("Unlucky the computer won!\n");
}


void end(){
    printf("Game has ended!\n");
    
    
}





int main()
{
   
   
    intro();
   
    printf("Would you like an example to demostrate?\n");
    printf("Yes [1] / No [2]\n");
    scanf("%d", &answer);
   
    if( answer == 1 )
    {   example();
        printf("\n\n");
         game();
    }
    else
    {   printf("\n\n");
        game();
       
    }
   
   
   
    end();
    
    printf("Would you like play another game?\n");
    printf("Yes [1] / No [2]\n");
    scanf("%d", &answer);
    if( answer == 1)
    {
        main();
    }
    else {
    printf("Thanks for playing MORRA - ODDS AND EVEN.");
    }
    
    
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the game function, there is a lot of code duplication which can be reduced.  In the (menu_choice == 2) point calculation is incorrect. And I suggest not to recursively call main function, try using some logic

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
int main()
{
    for(;;) // Infinite loop. -- equivalent of while(1) if you prefer.
    {
        intro();
   
        printf("Would you like an example to demostrate?\n");
        printf("Yes [1] / No [2]\n");
        scanf("%d", &answer);
   
        if( answer == 1 )
        {   example();
            printf("\n\n");
             game();
        }
        else
        {   printf("\n\n");
            game();
       
        }
   
        end();
    
        printf("Would you like play another game?\n");
        printf("Yes [1] / No [2]\n");
        scanf("%d", &answer);
        
        if( answer != 1)
        {
            printf("Thanks for playing MORRA - ODDS AND EVEN.");
            break; 
            //^___ exit the infinite loop.
        }
    }      

    return 0;
}
```

Recalling the `main` you should definitely not, in almost any case. Just create loops if you want to repeat everything.

Comment: `while(1)` would be easier to understand

Comment: @impopularGuy I personally dislike `while(1)` and I think `for(;;)` communicates the intention better. But I agree, it probably is easier to understand since most people are familiar with that instead. I added it as a comment.